# Virtualbox crashes on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, kernel, virtualbox

I installed Virtualbox from Terminal, everything apparently was OK but when I tried to launch my virtual machine, Virtualbox said that Kernel driver (rc = -1908) wasn't installed and recommended me to execute `modprobe vbox` on Terminal so, as my first attempt to solve the problem, I execute `modprobe...` and was something wrong, on the screen appear this text

```
modprobe: FATAL: Module vbox not found in directory /lib/modules/4.4.0-38-generic
```

After that I have tried to install `dkms`, but still the problem was there.
I have read different tutorials about the same problem with VirtualBox but no one reported me a solution (of course I change the boot mode on UEFI),most of the solutions drive me to a responses saying that a path is not found or not existent.
Also removing the program and reinstalling everything again wasn't useful.

Comment: Will you edit your question and append the command you're typing and the full output of the install attempt?